# Copy .tfw files from one folder in to subfolders based on name

Tags: batch-file, copy, filenames, subdirectory

I have a set of .tfw files which I need to copy in to sub-folders based upon name.

The tfw files all start with two capital letters. e.g. `HP40NE.TFW`

These two capital letters are used to make the subfolders. However, the sub-folders are all in lower case so in this example the subfolder name would be `hp`.

The files are in the folder: `C:\nfs01\core\osgb\OSGB_VML`

The sub-folders are in `C:\nfs01\core\osgb\OSGB_VML\GREYSCALE_161018`.

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Edit.....

So within the GREYSCALE_161018 folder are the subfolders. hp ht, hu, hw, hx, hy, hz, na, nb, nc, nd, nf, ng, nh, nj, nk, nl, nm, nn, no, nr, ns, nt, nu, nw, nx, ny, nz, ov, sd, se, sh, sj, sk, sm, sn, so, sp, sr, ss, st, su, sv, sw, sx, sy, sz, ta, tf, tg, tl, tm, tq, tr, tv. There are tfw files that correspond to each of these sub folders. The tfw files are in the folder OSGB_VML.

Comment: Unless you are able to show some code you have attempted you are not likely to have someone write it for you.

Comment: NTFS is not case sensitive.  You say the sub folder name is **hp**, but I do not see that in your folder path examples.

Comment: So within the GREYSCALE_161018 folder are the subfolders. hp
ht, hu, hw, hx, hy, hz, na, nb, nc, nd, nf, ng, nh, nj, nk, nl, nm, nn, no, nr, ns, nt, nu, nw, nx, ny, nz, ov, sd, se, sh, sj, sk, sm, sn, so, sp, sr, ss, st, su, sv, sw, sx, sy, sz, ta, tf, tg, tl, tm, tq, tr, tv. There are tfw files that correspond to each of these sub folders. The tfw files are in the folder OSGB_VML.

Comment: @jwpfox I wish i could provide some code, but i'm very new to this. Please be gentle :)

Comment: @C.Lumb I'm not attempting to be mean. I am suggesting that SO may not be the site for you to ask this question in the way you are asking it. You might have better luck in forums that are more receptive to the question you are asking. While I am typing, do you really require this program to be written as a batch file. Would any of the other scripting languages meet your needs? Beyond all of the above your question is still not clear enough to be answered. You aren't getting what is in your head onto the page in a meaningful way.